# Importing shapefiles to a postgis on a remote server

Tags: postgis, shapefile, pgsql2shp

I have two servers X and Y. X contains a postgis instance whereas Y doesn't have postgis installed, but connects to the postgis instance on X through a connector in nodejs.

I want the node script to import some shapefiles which is normally done with the pgsql2shp command. However since pgsql2shp isn't installed on server Y I can't just call the command.

Is there a way to call the pgsql2shp command (or do it's equivalent) through a query? Or should I just have the script on Y ssh to server X and run the command?

Answer (score 3):

IMO it depends on what kind of access you have on **db-server Y** and the import format matters allways.

**Push variant**

You could redirect the output of `shp2pgsql ...` command from the **maschine X** to **db-server Y** with:

```
    $ shp2pgsql ... |  psql -h some_host_name -d some_database_name ...
```

(assuming you are in a unixoid environment).

But the **db-server Y** will not understand what  `shp2pgsql ...`  on **maschine X** is generating and talking about without a postgis extension.

**Pull variant**

On the other you could import not postgis stuff like plain text files via COPY from inside the psql prompt and use tools like ssh to taylor the stuff before.

```
  $ psql some_database_on_maschine_y
  > \! ssh maschine_X some_converstion_tool_to_please_psql > result_on_maschine_Y
  > COPY table_name FROM 'result_on_maschine_Y'
```

... or if you have generated some sql stuff as seen before..

```
  > \i 'result_on_maschine_Y'
```

If you exchange `some_converstion_tool_to_please_psql` with `shp2pgsql` it describes the push variant.

**@Added central node.js variant**

I'm not familar with node.js but following the examples above, you could combine a [reader](https://github.com/geopipes/shapefile-stream) and a [writer](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) on our node.js environment. Here a plain non JSON example:

Create a shapefile with examples

The attributes

```
$ dbfcreate points -s NAME 20 -n ZIP 6 0
$ dbfadd points 'Greifswald 1' 17489
$ dbfadd points 'Greifswald 2' 17491
$ dbfadd points 'Greifswald 3' 17493
```

The geometry

```
$ shpcreate points point
$ shpadd points 54.0954 13.3786
$ shpadd points 54.0831 13.4061
$ shpadd points 54.1802 13.3435
```

Assuming the database table on db-server.Y:

```
$ psql nodejs
 CREATE TABLE points (
     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
     name VARCHAR(20), 
     zip  INTEGER);

 SELECT AddGeometryColumn('points', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

Node script...

```
var tk = require('util');                     // forma statement 
var shpfile   = require('shapefile-stream');  // shapefile stream
var through   = require('through2');          // transform and insert something
var pg        = require('pg');   
var srcUrl    = 'file://home/user/points.shp'       
var dburl     = 'postgres://user:secret@db-server.Y:5432/nodejs';
var dbclient  = new pg.Client(dburl);
var srid      = 4326;
var table     = 'points';
dbclient.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
shpfile.createReadStream( srcUrl ).pipe( through.obj( function( data, enc, next ){
    var record = tk.format("INSERT INTO %s (name, zip, geom) VALUES ( '%s',%d, ST_SETSRID(ST_POINT(%f, %f), %d)) RETURNING ID",
                           table,
                           data.properties.NAME,data.properties.ZIP,
                           data.geometry.coordinates[0],
                           data.geometry.coordinates[1],
                           srid);
    console.log("DEBUG: ", record);
    dbclient.query(record,
                   function(err, result) {
                       if (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                       }
                   });
    next();
}));
...
```

Comment: Machine Y has neither psql or shp2pgsql installed; only a node server that can talk to the database that's on machine X.

Comment: @apricity Are you will be able to run psql from server X `server.x$ psql -d dbname -h server.y -U....` to connect to the db server?

Comment: Yes, but X IS the db server. I think you have the variables flopped; I should've named them better. But my point is that on the node machine psql and shp2pgsql is not installed. I can only use this connector inside node to communicate to the db-server: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres to talk to the db-server.

Answer (score 2):

Given that *"Machine Y has neither psql or shp2pgsql installed"* but does have access to the shapefiles, you could try to transform those shapefiles in server Y into some plaintext format and push them though the node connector into machine X.

For example, with [node's shapefile package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile) you could transform shapefiles into geojsons and have them insterted into the database at server X using postgis' [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) function.

Comment: What if the shapefiles are in a projection not supported by GeoJSON?

Comment: I think you could reproject them using something like [gdal for node](http://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/gdal.html)

Comment: Better still, using [ST_Transform](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html)